# Index was outside the bounds of the array in Threadpool in c#

Tags: c#, threadpool

I create a simple programe in c# using thread pool while i pass the Thread number as parameter but i get exception (Run-time exception (line 19): Index was outside the bounds of the array.)

```
using System;
using System.Threading; 
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
        private const byte TotalNoOfThread=10;
        private int[] arrThreadRowProcessed;
        private bool[] arrThreadRowIsCompleted;
        private void ResetThread()
        {
            arrThreadRowProcessed = new int[TotalNoOfThread];
            arrThreadRowIsCompleted = new bool[TotalNoOfThread];
        }
    
        private  void TuroverDayWise(int ThreadNo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From THread ="+ThreadNo);
            arrThreadRowIsCompleted[ThreadNo] = true; //Geting error on this point Index value show 10 but how
        }
        public void TuroverDayWise()
        {
            ResetThread();
            Console.WriteLine("Reset the Data..");
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalNoOfThread; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(x=>TuroverDayWise(i)));
            }
            while (arrThreadRowIsCompleted.Any(p => !p))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);                
            }

        }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program obj= new Program();         
        obj.TuroverDayWise();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)

Comment: not clear, can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line...

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(x=>TuroverDayWise(i)));
```

the current value of i is used (which is incremented outside), not the value, when it was called. You could try to save the i value in a temporary variable, this should work:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalNoOfThread; i++)
        {
            int local = i;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(x => TuroverDayWise(local)));
        }
```